# Why am I getting an "undefined reference to" error. (linker issue using make)

Tags: c, makefile, linker, ld

I know there are a lot of questions similar to this one, but none of them seem to answer my question. I am writing unit test code and I am calling the following function,

```
ads1259_init(&settings, &storage);
```

which is supposed to init a faux spi communication on x86. However, I am getting the linker error undefined reference to `ads1259_init'.

I have defined the function in the header file as

```
StatusCode ads1259_init(Ads1259Settings* settings, Ads1259Storage* storage);
```

and in the .c file as

```
StatusCode ads1259_init(Ads1259Settings* settings, Ads1259Storage* storage) {...}
```

We are using make for our build system (which I know very little about), and the make file for the driver library which should be called when I run the command `make test LIBRARY=ms-drivers PLATFORM=x86` which tests all the drivers in that directory is:

```
# Defines $(T)_SRC, $(T)_INC, $(T)_DEPS, and $(T)_CFLAGS for the build makefile.
# Tests can be excluded by defining $(T)_EXCLUDE_TESTS.
# Pre-defined:
# $(T)_SRC_ROOT: $(T)_DIR/src
# $(T)_INC_DIRS: $(T)_DIR/inc{/$(PLATFORM)}
# $(T)_SRC: $(T)_DIR/src{/$(PLATFORM)}/*.{c,s}

$(T)_DEPS := $(PLATFORM_LIB) libcore

ifeq (x86,$(PLATFORM))
$(T)_test_ltc_afe_MOCKS := spi_exchange
endif
```

I am confused because there are about 8 other drivers that use the same make file, and are set up with the exact same file structure as mine. They all test fine when I comment out this line and run the command. I am using VS code, and all of our builds happen in vagrant, a linux virtual box. I believe the issue is that the linker is not finding the .c implementation, but I can't figure out why.
If anyone has any suggestions they would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does your link command look like?  Does it specify all of the needed object files?  If not, then fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Answered: I was building on the wrong platform, so linker was looking in wrong directory